# listView selecting multiple items

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a Fragment that runs from nav bar. This ListView contains 4 elements and I want to make the choice multiple, with redirecting to another activity.
Should I make Activities for all these choices, making it like if else if statement, or is there is an easier way to do it? New activities will contain data about every catagory.
Here is my Fragment

```
public class Caffes extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
final  String[] items=new String[]{"Urban Style","Unic concept","Small and cosy","Coffe to go"};

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public Caffes() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static Caffes newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    Caffes fragment = new Caffes();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fcaffes,container,false);
    ListView list=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {   //arg2-position,
          if(arg2==1) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(this, Liked.class);
              intent.putExtra("position", arg2);
              startActivity(intent);


          }
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Yea!!! click called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    return view;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a method to create a new activity with Intent, and in the intent would put the variables you want to add. Then I would call the method in each if else.

Instead of using if else you can use the switch function!

Hope it helps